# Who washed the Prophet's(PBUH) Janaza?

Tags: history, prophet-muhammad, sahaba

- Who were the persons(sahabas)R.A washed the Prophet's(PBUH)
  Janasa(deadbody)?
- Who was the Imam for the funeral prayer of Prophet(PBUH)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are an arabic reader check this [article from IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=145791)(which can also be translated to English) that states that the persons who washed the Prophet were: the prophet's family members who were: **Al-Abbas, Ali, Al-Fadl and Kuthm (Al Abbas' sons), Shakran (the prophet's servant), Usama bin Zaid, and Aous bin Khawlah**. However they washed him wearing his clothes, they didn't put his clothes off, then they enshrouded him by three clothes.

The answer to the prayer is also found in the above link, there was **no** Imam who prayed, the Muslims prayed each one alone on the Prophet (PBUH); the men, then the women, then the children. After that they buried him where he died.

Comment: I think this answer is from the Shia perspective, wasn't Abu Bakr (RA) the one that shrouded Prophet (PBUH)?

Answer (score 4):

Imam Ali a.s. washed him directly but companions of Imam Ali a.s. helped him in pouring water and etc. also the first one who offered the Janasa prayer was Imam Ali a.s. and then male Sahaba and then female Sahaba. The Prophet SAWW was buried in his own home and the room was small few persons could enter and offer prayer and all could not pray together.

**Reference:**

[www.andisheqom.com](http://www.andisheqom.com/Files/news/newsIn.php?lang=fa&id=2350&cat=5)

Answer (score 1):

When the Janazah of the Prophet (صلي الله عليه وسلم) was ready, then people came in groups and read the Janazah Salaah. Because the Janazah was inside the Hujrah Mubaarak, only few people at a time entered and read the Janazah Salaah and left, then others followed, but there was no Imam. [Madarijun Nabuiwat]

Ahmed Raza Khan رضي الله عنه states as follows in the fourth volume of his world renowned encyclopaedia Fatawa-e-Razviyah:

> The Ulama have differences on the issue of the Janazah Salaah of the Prophet صلي الله عليه وسلم. One Jama’at says that the Janazah Namaaz did not really occur. Small groups came in and sent Durood and Salaams and then left, followed by others.
>
> There are also many Ulama who accept this Namaaz Maroof. Imam Qaazi Iyaaz رضي الله عنه rectified this. Hazrat Abu Bakr Siddique رضي الله عنه was engrossed in giving hope to the Muslims and taking care of the needs of the Ummah. At this time, the allegiance had not been taken on his hands. People came in huge and small groups and continued to pray the Janazah Salaah of Rasoolullah صلي الله عليه وسلم.When the Allegiance was taken on the hands of Hazrat Abu Bakr Siddique رضي الله عنه and his Guardianship was confirmed, He prayed the Janazah Salaah, and after him non other prayed, as mentioned by Imam Shamsul Ulama Sarkhasi رضي الله عنه. 
>   [Fatawa Razvia vol.4. pg 54 - New Edition of Fatawa Razvia Vol.9 pg.286]